# Skipping from a spec in wdio

Tags: jasmine, webdriver-io

I am having a scenario like i need to skip the spec while automating when 3 "it" blocks are failed.
I am using wdio with jasmine framwork.
Can anyone knows a way to sort this out.

I tried modifying the after test hook.But failed.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `x` in front of an `it` to make it `xit` to skip the test.

You can also add an `x` in front of a `describe` to make it `xdescribe` to skip that `describe` block.

Likewise, you can add an `f` in front of an `it` to make it `fit` to focus on that test.

You can also add an `f` in front of a `describe` to make it `fdescribe` to focus on that `describe` block.

Comment: Thanks. But my actual requirement is to skip test cases/it during automation if a specific condition is false.